# Weird spacing in environment

Tags: spacing, environments

In the following MWE example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{myitem}{\item}{}%

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \begin{myitem}
    Item \hfill\textbf{(Text)}
  \end{myitem}

  \begin{myitem}
    Item \hfill{\textbf{(Text)}}
  \end{myitem}

  \item Item \hfill{\textbf{(Text)}}

  \item Item \hfill{\textbf{(Text)}}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

The output looks like this
[image: MWE output]

Notice that for my environment `myitem`, the spacing is not quite right. I can fix this by requiring the user of `myitem` to add `%` right after `\end{myitem}`.

Why is the environment behaving differently from the the command `\item`? Also, is there a way to change the definition of `myitem` so that adding `%` is not needed?

Comment: Not sure but this might be related to my previous problem: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/527064/newdocumentenvironment-and-xparse-combination-adds-unwanted-space-after/527073#527073

Comment: Rmove trailing spaces.

Comment: `\newenvironment{myitem}{\item}{\ignorespacesafterend}`

Comment: Thank you all. `\ignorespacesafterend` is exactly what I was looking for. I will try to close this question and mark it as duplicate.